# When should a Demon Slayer use guns instead of their sword?

Tags: demon-slayer

I'm well aware that Kimetsu no Yaiba takes place during the Taisho era, which is from 1912 to 1926. During this era, guns are relatively new to Japan, and from my understanding, they were considered too harsh for the public, and as such were prohibited (though police officers were starting to equip pistols and rifles around this time).

Now, it's made very transparent that the [Demon Slayer Corps](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Demon_Slayer_Corps) is not an official governmental agency:

> There are hundreds of Demon Slayers within the organization, however, they are not officially recognized by the government.

This implies that Demon Slayers would not be permitted to use guns, yet in the manga, we get our first exposure to guns being utilized by a Demon Slayer...

> ... in volume 13, chapter 107, when Genya uses his Nichirin Shotgun against Sekido and Karaku.

With that being said, I've only made it to volume 14 so far and my searches on the web have yielded no results.

---

Is it ever explained in the manga, whether directly or indirectly, when a demon slayer may or may not use specific weapons such as guns?

<sub>*Please be sure to use spoiler tags in your answer where applicable.*</sub>

Comment: I note that guns were first introduced in the 13th century, and took off with the 16th century and the new Portuguese guns.  There was a period where they were forcibly suppressed, but they came back with Perry's forcibly opening the country.

Comment: This is a sword fighting story that takes place when carrying swords were banned (a.k.a. "may not use"), let alone guns...

Answer (score 2):

Demon Slayer Corps is not officially recognized by the government, so they don't have to follow government rules. The Nichirin shotgun used by Genya is a modified weapon which help his shortcomings of not able to use breathing styles. Note that other demon slayers use breathing styles and swords is the weapon of choice to match with this style. Guns might hold potential in upcoming battles against the Upper Moon Rank demons but the demon corps like to stick with old-school weapons. [Have fun watching this parody video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tXkimcV1lVs)

Source: https://www.spieltimes.com/tv-shows/anime/why-does-genya-use-a-gun-instead-of-a-nichirin-blade-in-demon-slayer/#google_vignette